# Ассемблер, выскакивает ошибка в дебагере: "Divide by zero" (деление на ноль)

Tags: ассемблер, исключения

Я компилирую код через DosBOX, позже в дебагере выскакивает следующая ошибка: "Divide by zero" (Исключение: деление на ноль)

Вот собственно и код:

```
.model small
.stack
.data

    a dw 2
    b dw 2
    c dw 4
    d dw 4

.code
main:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, d   
    div b

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
end main
```

Comment: Раз у вас есть дебаггер убедитесь, что ds указывает действительно на ваш сегмент данных. хотя  я и не вижу причин что бы это было не так.

Comment: Что происходит если попробовать `mov bx, b` `div bx`?

Comment: @jfs, всё равно пишет divide by zero, и кстати это происходит, когда я второй раз считываю код, то есть первый раз код весь считывается успешно, пишет terminated exit code 0, потом program already terminated, Reload?, а вот после этого уже на строчке с div пишет divide by zero

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение, что результат зависит от содержимого регистра DX. При первом проходе отладчик обнуляет его, а вот какое значение туда попадает после Reload - неизвестно. И Divide by zero может возникать, если частное не помещается в AX. Вот всяком случае явное обнуление DX перед делением (помним, что при двухбайтном делителе делимым является пара AX:DX, и явно инициализировать всю эту пару программист *обязан*) подобную ошибку устраняет. А почему именно такая диагностика - фиг знает, давно уже всё эти тасмы/масмы в руках не держал :) Во всяком случае нечто вроде "Arithmetic overflow" в TASM это вообще ошибка трансляции, а не времени исполнения.